# data retrieval between two DateTime object with equal intervals Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am new to rails and  I think this is common problem. Currently, I have two different method in rails to fetch data for today and week. Then I filter the data to find max value for each hour in today method and max for each day in case of week method and return json object accordingly.

Now I want to remove the constraint from my rest api, by writing a method which will find difference between two dates and find the interval between them, the difference could be in minutes, hours, days, etc.  Then the difference would be divided into 10 equal parts and find extract the max for that particular part. For example, if the parts are in the gap of 10 mins then I need max of each one, similar for hours or day.

Finding difference is easy but I do not understand how to process further, any pointers please, I strongly believe that many people has experienced similar issue and would be nice if I can get any good pointer basically in rails.

My datetime format is

```
Mon Jun 23 16:00:06 2014 GMT 0200
```

Comment: "I do not understand how to process future", do you mean that you do not know how to go forward in solving the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I meant further, in details means, how do I decide the parts should be in minutes, hours or days as I do not want more then 10 parts, I hope I am clear

Answer (score 1):

Provided that seconds of accuracy is sufficient you can compare two DateTime objects by simple subtraction:

```
a = DateTime.new(2014) # Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 +0000
b = DateTime.new(2015) # Thu, 01 Jan 2015 00:00:00 +0000
diff = b.to_i - a.to_i # in seconds.
puts "2014 has #{ (diff / 1.day).round } days"
```

ActiveSupport gives us methods on which we can use to convert integers to time
which makes it really easy to add a tenth of diff

```
puts "a tenth into 2014 is #{ a + (diff / 10).seconds }"
```

You can use pass a range of DateTime objects into a where clause:

```
Foo.where(created_at: a..(a + (diff / 10).seconds))
```

So to wrap it all up:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Get the maximum value of bar column 
    #   for divided into periods between a start and end date.
    # @param start [DateTime]
    # @param finish [DateTime]
    # @param divisor [Integer] the number of parts to split into
    # @return array 
    #   will always have divisor number of elements
    #   elements may be empty 
    def maximum_bar_values_for_period(start, finish, divisor = 10)
        diff = finish.to_i - start.to_i
        part = diff / divisor
        (0..divisor).map do |i|
            start_period = start + ((i - 1) * part).seconds
            end_peroid =  start_period + part.seconds
            Foo.where(created_at: start_period..end_peroid).maximum(:bar)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Note that this will create 10 database queries which is not great for performance. If you want to do it in one query you will probably need to write the SQL yourself.